# Jenkins build command fails while building mobile app in Mac

Tags: macos, react-native, jenkins, npm-install, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to build a hybrid mobile app (written in React Native library) using Jenkins. The Jenkins is installed & configured in a local Mac machine & Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) is the Source Code Management tool. When I initiate the build the workspace is being created properly and also the source code is imported into the workspace. But after that the ***npm install*** command is getting failed. Below given is the exact error I am getting in Jenkins console. Could someone please help me figure out this issue ?

```
18:50:28 npm ERR! file sh
18:50:28 npm ERR! path sh
18:50:28 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
18:50:28 npm ERR! errno ENOENT
18:50:28 npm ERR! syscall spawn sh
18:50:28 npm ERR! core-js@2.6.10 postinstall: `node postinstall || echo "ignore"`
18:50:28 npm ERR! spawn sh ENOENT
18:50:28 npm ERR! 
18:50:28 npm ERR! Failed at the core-js@2.6.10 postinstall script.
18:50:28 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
18:50:29 
18:50:29 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
18:50:29 npm ERR!     /Users/Shared/Jenkins/.npm/_logs/2019-10-21T13_20_28_829Z-debug.log
18:50:29 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
18:50:29 Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Does the command work fine when you run it locally without Jenkins?

Comment: @DibakarAditya - Yes. When I run the same command in terminal as root user I was able to complete the npm install successfully.